# Send mail through code without opening MailComposer or new view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, email

In my application i want to send mail to some one.

If i use following code new window for gets opened for mail.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:string]];
```

And if i use MailComposer then same controller will shown for mail.

But i want to send mail direct from my code by opening any screen or view in my application, with the help of mail address, subject and body part.

Any help ?

Comment: The reason Apple don't provide a specific mail API and instead recommend you use 'MFMailComposeViewController' is because they deem email a user driven operation. Therefore, any app sending email in the background without the users consent or acknowledgement is likely to be instantly rejected.

Comment: means it is not possible?in my app i have to send password to some email address how can i do it without showing password?

Comment: That already sounds incredibly suspicious. What's the password for? Why can't the user of the app see the password?

Comment: ya if he forgot password what can i do thats my question was, i wanna send password by mail to him through my app.

Comment: Is the password for your app?

Comment: ya password for sending my app

Comment: I would suggest either not password restricting your app, or if it really is a requirement then when the user first creates the password also ask him/her to enter a memorable word or phrase. If they forget the password then you can instead prompt them for the memorable word or phrase and then once entered correctly prompt them again for a new password, which is more secure than just showing them the old one. Also, you should never store a password. Instead you should store a hash of the password which you then compare to a hash of what the user enters when they wish to enter/unlock the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[download the sample code from skpsmtpmessage - Google Code and ran that.](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/source/browse/#svn/trunk/SMTPSender)
You might require to change few things but it will work.

Comment: thanks for your help but i solve my problem with the help of            http://iphonesdksnippets.com/?tag=/smtp

Answer (score 0):

Hoping not to sound too advertise-y, but you can easily do this with [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com).

All you have to do is make an API call with your API Key, the content of your email (or a template name) and make an HTTP POST request to our API server, and ta daaaa, it sends through. We currently have a few iPhone apps doing this very thing.

As an act of fairness, you can take a look at all of the services available for such an activity and you can choose which suits your needs:

- [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com)
- [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com)
- [PostmarkApp](http://postmarkapp.com)
- [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

(**Full Disclosure:** I am the Product Manager of PostageApp.)